# How to get the selected element of the iOS Voiceover

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, voiceover

I have an iOS Swift App and i want to detect which element is selected by the voiceover.

Have tried to send an UIAccessibilitySwitchControlStatusDidChangeNotification but i don't get this to work.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
            self,
            selector: "handleVoiceoverSelection",
            name: UIAccessibilitySwitchControlStatusDidChangeNotification,
            object: nil)
```

...

```
func handleVoiceoverSelection(){
    println("!!!! element selected !!!!")
}
```

Is there any way?

Comment: What have you already tried? (actual code not the method you're wanting to use) [See this article on how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why would you need this? What larger problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe check out UIAccessibilityFocus?

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibilityFocus_Protocol/index.html